# zero knowledge encryption with keycloak

Tags: encryption, cryptography, keycloak, data-storage

Here is my structure:

- A database where I store sensitive information.
- A frontend app where the user interacts.
- A backend to receive interactions and manage data accordingly
- Keycloak for auth

[image: Architecture]

I have been reading a little bit, and I have concluded that storing sensitive information in the database could pose security risks.

A solution could be to use zero knowledge encryption:

1. user authenticates with password
2. frontend uses the password to encrypt data sent to the backend
3. backend stores encrypted data

The problem is that I have no access to the password since Keycloak stores it internally.
Do you guys know if there is a way of implementing a solution like this? or a better alternative? I am new to cryptography.

Comment: How do you solve an edge case when user will change a password?

Comment: I am not an expert in cryptography, nor know a lot about the protocol, but the first idea that comes to my mind is: 1. user creates a new password. 2 you decrypt all data that the user has encrypted. 3 you encrypt the data with the new password. 4. you return a successful confirmation. To avoid having to decrypt all data you could have an internal randomly generated password that is fixed and could be used as an intermediary. (you just have to decrypt the internal fixed password with the old password and encrypt with the new one). But I was hoping Keycloak would handle all of this.

Comment: IMHO you have incorrect expectations about Keycloak. Keycloak is IDP - Identity provider = it provides user identity primarly.